# Product search does not work due to addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection

Tags: magento-1.9, product, search

I have enabled my products visibility for both list page and search. 
But when I use

> Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($products);

the products does not displayed.

What does **addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection** do?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have installed a module. I think that module checks the products visibility with function **addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection**. But no products are displayed. I have checked my all products are visible in both catalog and search.
I am curious what exactly this function does? Because when I comment this function I can see my products.

Answer (score 1):

What happens in the function `addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection` is that the appropriate visibility filters are added to the collection.

When calling `addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection` you need to pass in a collection. This collection then gets used as follows.

```
$collection->setVisibility($this->getVisibleInSiteIds());
```

The function `getVisibleInSiteIds` returns an array containing the constants for each type of visibility.

```
return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
```

Now the function `setVisibility` us slightly more complex. What it does is set these values to a protected array of all collection limitations and then sets all limitations against the collection.

```
$this->_productLimitationFilters['visibility'] = $visibility;
$this->_applyProductLimitations();
```

But what this really boils down to is simply adding a filter to the collection.

```
if (isset($filters['visibility']) && !isset($filters['store_table'])) {
    $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
        ->quoteInto('cat_index.visibility IN(?)', $filters['visibility']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puiysh,Please use the  below

> $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
>       ->getVisibleInSiteIds());

I Suggestion please set current product collection Visibility using ;

> Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds();

Which  will only filter `('Catalog, Search') and ('Search')`  visibility status Products